# A,B,C,D,E,F are friends. Some, but not all, of them are friends with each other. All have the same number of friends. How many ways are there?

Tags: probability, combinations

A, B, C, D, E, and F have internet accounts. Some, **but not all**, of them are internet friends with each other, and none of them has an internet friend outside this group. Each of them has the **same number of internet friends**. In how many different ways can this happen?

[image: a. 60 b. 170 c. 290 d. 320 e. 660]

Could someone explain how to solve this, simplest possible way would be appreciated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Four cases arise i.e. $1$ or $2$ or $3$ or $4$ internet friends.

But case $1$ and $4$ and case $2$ and $3$ are analogous because no of ways of choosing friends is same as no of ways of choosing non-friends(people you don't want to be friends with).

**Case 1 or 4:**

When each person has one friend we just have to find the number of ways of dividing them in groups of two.
$$\frac{^6C_2\times^4C_2\times^2C_2}{3!}=15$$

**Case 2 or 3:**

Here there are again two cases:

(i) Making them sit around circular table, then the people sitting next to a specific person are his friends.
$$\frac{(6-1)!}{2}=60$$

(ii) Another case is two groups of three friends which are mutually exclusive to each other.
$$\frac{^6C_3}{2}=10$$

Therefore, total no of ways $=2\times(15+(10+60))=170$ ways